# Derivation of the Lever Rule

Tags: thermodynamics

To derive the Lever rule, the textbook I am reading sets:

$$nz_A = n_\alpha x_A + n_\beta y_A\\ nz_A = n_\alpha z_A + n_\beta z_A$$

$x_A =$ liquid phase mole fraction of component $A$

$y_A =$ gas phase mole fraction of component $A$

$n_A=$ amount of phase $A \ \text{in mol}\ (A=\alpha \ \text{or} \ \beta)$

$z_A=$ overall composition

"Overall composition" sounds to me like $z_A=x_A+y_A$, but the equation suggests $x_A = z_A = y_A$ which doesn't make sense so I think I'm missing an assumption that is made or I'm misunderstanding the equation.